# Malloc() failing when long long data type used

Tags: c, malloc

The code below, prints out all the prime numbers between [m,n].
When I use unsigned int,malloc works perfectly till `10^9` as expected on my 64-bit system.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdbool.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <time.h>

  #define true 1 
  #define false 0

  void SieveOfEratosthenes(unsigned int m ,unsigned int n) {
      bool *prime;
      prime = (bool*)malloc(m - n + 2);
      if (!prime) {
          printf("FAIL\n");
          return;
      }
      memset(prime, true, (m - n + 2));
      unsigned int i = 2;
      for (i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
          if (prime[i] == true) {
              for (unsigned int j = i * 2; j <= n; j += i)
                  prime[j] = false;
          }
      }
      for (i = m; i <= n; i++)
          if (prime[i] && i != 1)
              printf("%u  \n", i);
  }

  int main() {
      clock_t begin,end;
      unsigned int m, n;
      scanf("%u %u", &m, &n);
      begin = clock();
      SieveOfEratosthenes(m, n);
      end = clock();
      double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      printf("\nTime Taken : %lf secs\n", time_spent);
      return 0;
  }
```

But when I change from `unsigned int` to `unsigned long long`, for bigger values, `malloc` fails for every value, even for small ones. Why doesn't this work?

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdbool.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <time.h>

  #define true 1 
  #define false 0

  void SieveOfEratosthenes(unsigned long long m, unsigned long long n) {
      bool *prime;
      prime = (bool*)malloc(m - n + 2);
      if (!prime) {
          printf("FAIL\n");
          return;
      }
      memset(prime, true, (m - n + 2));
      unsigned long long i = 2;
      for (i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
          if (prime[i] == true) {
              for (unsigned long long j = i * 2; j <= n; j += i)
                  prime[j] = false;
          }
      }
      for (i = m; i <= n; i++)
          if (prime[i] && i != 1)
              printf("%llu  \n", i);
  }

  int main() {
      clock_t begin,end;
      unsigned long long m, n;
      scanf("%llu %llu", &m, &n);
      begin = clock();
      SieveOfEratosthenes(m,n);
      end = clock();
      double time_spent=(double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
      printf("\nTime Taken : %lf secs\n", time_spent);
      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: What is `size_t` on your system? (as `malloc` takes a `size_t` as input)

Comment: (code review: Why don't you just `#include<stdbool.h>`?)

Comment: malloc also needs size like -> `malloc (whatever_nbr * sizeof(data_type))`. use the `sizeof()` operator to allocate the memory accordingly.

Comment: Please show the inputs you give that produce the undesired output

Comment: Your size calculation is `m - n + 2`, which is negative for `m == 1` and `n == 100`. You'll have to make sure `m >= n`. (But then your loop `i = m; i <= n; i++` will do nothing). Seems you've got a few logic problems

Comment: What happens if you do: `size_t reqMem = ( m - n + 2) * sizeof( bool ); prime = (bool*)malloc( reqMem );`

Comment: You also need to validate your input parameters to prevent underflow and overflow in the sum

Comment: @M.M I realized that, all I had to do was `n-m+2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because of this:

```
      unsigned int m, n;
      scanf("%llu %llu", &m, &n);
```

Furthermore, you do not allocate the proper amount of memory:

```
      prime = (bool*)malloc(m - n + 2);
```

if `m` is less than `n + 2`, the size become a huge number. It only works be chance for `unsigned int` because you are able to allocate 4GB or possibly 16GB of memory on your system.

As a matter of fact, given your algorithm, you must allocate `n + 1` elements because you index this array with numbers starting at 2 during the sieve.

Furthermore, you should use `unsigned char` instead of `bool` for this array because he type `bool` can be larger than 1 byte.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void SieveOfEratosthenes(unsigned long long m, unsigned long long n) {
    unsigned char *prime = malloc(n + 1);
    if (!prime) {
        printf("FAIL\n");
        return;
    }
    memset(prime, 1, n + 1);
    unsigned long long i, j;
    for (i = 2; i * i <= n; i++) {
        if (prime[i]) {
            for (j = i * 2; j <= n; j += i)
                prime[j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = m; i <= n; i++) {
        if (prime[i] && i != 1)
            printf("%llu\n", i);
    }
}

int main() {
    clock_t begin, end;
    unsigned long long int m, n;
    if (scanf("%llu %llu", &m, &n) == 2) {
        begin = clock();
        SieveOfEratosthenes(m, n);
        end = clock();
        double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        printf("\nTime Taken : %f secs\n", time_spent);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is possible to use a separate array for the prime candidates and the sieve slice, it becomes necessary for slices of very large numbers. Try allocating an array for the prime candidates of size `ceil(sqrt(n + 1))` and perform the sieve on that, than allocate an array for the slice and perform the sieve on that with the correct offsets and initial values, using the prime numbers from the first array.

Here is a naive implementation:

```
void SieveOfEratosthenes(unsigned long long m, unsigned long long n) {
    unsigned int maxp = (unsigned int)(ceil(sqrt(n)) + 1);
    unsigned char *composite = calloc(maxp, 1);
    unsigned char *slice = calloc(n - m + 1, 1);
    if (!composite || !slice) {
        free(composite);
        free(slice);
        printf("FAIL\n");
        return;
    }
    /* compute the primes */
    unsigned int p, q;
    for (p = 2; p * p < maxp; p++) {
        if (!composite[p]) {
            for (q = p * 2; q < maxp; q += p)
                composite[p] = 1;
        }
    }
    /* sieve the slice */
    unsigned long long i;
    if (m == 0)
        slice[0] = 1;
    if (m <= 1 && n >= 1)
        slice[1 - m] = 1;
    for (p = 2; p < maxp; p++) {
        if (!composite[p]) {
            i = 2 * p;
            if (i < m) {
                i = m - m % p;
                if (i < m)
                    i += p;
            }
            while (i <= n) {
                slice[i - m] = 1;
                i += p;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = m; i <= n; i++) {
        if (!slice[i - m])
            printf("%llu\n", i);
    }
    free(composite);
    free(slice);
}
```

Comment: and OP should have gotten warnings from those.

Comment: He's using malloc() - there's copious undefined, unspecified and implementation defined behaviours to worry about!

Comment: This is embarrassing, I realized I was doing `m-n+2` instead of `n-m+2`.
So as you said, it was working for `unsigned int` by chance.

Comment: I don't understand why the OP has not added diagnostic line like `printf( "%llu %llu\n", m, n)` before `malloc()` (if there is no IDE debugger).